# Official way to access / download github files from scripts?

Tags: curl, github, wget, github-api

An often given tip how to access / download a specific file from a github repository is to use rawgit, e.g.:

```
curl https://rawgit.com/webmin/webmin/master/os_list.txt
```

this will give you the current version of the file from webmin github repository.

Nevertheless there is a BIG downside doing this for production scripts, because you will be blocked if a rawgit URL is used to often. This is also stated on rawgit.com:

> Use this URL for development
>
> New changes you push to GitHub will be reflected within minutes.
>   Excessive traffic will be throttled and blacklisted.

I was in contact with githup support to get unblocked after intensive development and got the answer to use github API instead of rawgit!

Question: How to use github API to retrieve a specific file from a github repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer**: Use an URL in the format

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path?ref=tag/commit/branch
```

**and** the `Accept:application/vnd.github.v3.raw` header set.

---

To fetch the`os-lists.txt` file from the example above use:

```
curl -s -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.v3.raw" https://api.github.com/repos/webmin/webmin/contents/os_lists.txt
```

---

Explanation:

- `https://api.github.com/repos/` base URL of github API
- `:owner/:repo/` replace this with the name of owner and repository
- `:path` replace this with the path to the file within the repository
- `?ref=` optional argument to select branch, commit or tag to get the file from. If not specified you get the file from the repositories default branch

For more information see: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

- `Accept:application/vnd.github.v3.raw` header has to be set while to get the RAW file. Without this header you get the file information in JSON format:

```JSON
{
      "name": "os_list.txt",
      "path": "os_list.txt",
      "sha": "2fa32a1860063f47c9d9ddcfe73368329cef0ba1",
      "size": 31563,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/webmin/webmin/contents/os_list.txt?ref=master",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/webmin/webmin/blob/master/os_list.txt",
      "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/webmin/webmin/git/blobs/2fa32a1860063f47c9d9ddcfe73368329cef0ba1",
      "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webmin/webmin/master/os_list.txt",
      "type": "file",
      "content": "IyBQY......",
}
```

For more information see: https://developer.github.com/v3/

---

References:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

https://developer.github.com/v3/

https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme/pull/1083